# Why don't my backtesting MQL5code show any result on MT5?

Tags: mql5

I programmed a successfully compiled script code of trading on MetaEditor, but when I try to backtest it, Nothing appears as a result,. It seems that it don't take position despite of a good strategy to open and close position on the script. What would be the problem? Note that I can share the whole code to whom can help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.